# Como verificar se o campo type="file" foi preenchido

Tags: php

Eu tenho um formulário e tenho o seguinte campo

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="foto">Foto:</label>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" required>
</label>
```

Preciso de verificar através de php se o campo foi preenchido

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["fileToUpload"])) {
        $msg = "Por favor coloque uma imagem!.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Não se usa `$_POST` para um input file, usa o `$_FILES`

Comment: `if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {} else {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente fazer assim:

```
if (!isset($_FILE['fileToUpload'])) {
   $msg = "Por favor coloque uma imagem!.";
}
```

Comment: Assim só esta a criar uma variavel String, caso nao tenha ficheiro. Tem que mostrar a mensagem em algum lado.

    if (!isset($_FILE['fileToUpload'])) {
   $msg = "Por favor coloque uma imagem!.";
echo $msg;
}

Comment: Desnecessário seu comentário!

Answer (score 4):

Verifique se no form foi incluido o atributo: `enctype` e com o valor `multipart/form-data`. Esse valor é necessário quando você estiver usando formulários que têm um controle de upload de arquivo.

O atributo enctype especifica como o formulário de dados deverão ser codificadas quando enviá-lo para o servidor. Ele pode ser usado somente se o método for "post".

Sugestão do form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="foto">Foto:</label>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" required> 
        <input type="submit" value="Salvar" name="submit">  
    </div>
</form>
```

Validação:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    if (empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
        $msg = "Por favor coloque uma imagem!.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Caso faça um `var_dump($_FILES["fileToUpload"]);` será exibido alguns dados do arquivo que foi feito o upload.

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente você deve apenas trocar `$_POST` para `$_FILES`.

Eu tirei o `required` do seu html para que a validação funcione, então usando os dados que você passou, ficaria assim:

## [Veja o código em funcionamento](http://solutionsagencia.com.br/testephp2/).

HTML:

```
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post" action="validar.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="foto">Foto:</label>
        input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*">
        </label><br><br>
    <input id="btnenviar" name="btnenviar" type="submit" value="Validar" />
</form>
```

PHP (validar.php):

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        if (empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
            $msg = "Por favor coloque uma imagem!.";
            echo $msg;
        }
    }
?>
```